# how can i pin a new in my site?

Tags: php

in my php news script

i use this code for show title of news :

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT newsid,title FROM news WHERE cat='1' ORDER BY newsid DESC LIMIT 15");
?>
```

and show 10 news at database order by send date

but i want pin 3 news to show first :

for example:

newstitle3 (pined)
newstitle4 (pined)
newstitle6 (pined)
newstitle1
newstitle2
newstitle5
newstitle7
....

you see 3,4 and 6 are pinned news then show unpinned news

how can i add code in my database query for this news display?

Comment: `ORDER by pinned DESC, newsid DESC` should give you pinned entries first (if `pinned` is a boolean field)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Lets think one step ahead -

Taking into consideration that there might be other areas on your site that require this pinned items behavior - I recomend a slightly more complex yet robust solution.

A more generic way of settings "pinned" items would be to create a new "pinned_items" table in your database. You mention only news items but perhaps there are other areas in your site that will also (perhaps in the future) require this "pinned" behavior.

You could have a `pinned_items` table with this structure -

```
+----+----------+--------+
| id | obj_type | obj_id |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 |        1 |      1 |
|  2 |        1 |      2 |
|  3 |        1 |      3 |
|  4 |        2 |      4 |
|  5 |        2 |      5 |
|  6 |        2 |      6 |
+----+----------+--------+
```

The `obj_type` would reference the type of the item (lets consider type 1 to be a news item) and the `obj_id` would be a reference to your `news` table.

So to retrieve all the "pinned" news items, you would do a query similar to this -

```
SELECT newsItem.* FROM news AS newsItem
LEFT JOIN `pinned_items` AS pinnedItem ON pinnedItem.obj_id = newsItem.id 
WHERE pinnedItem.obj_type = 1
```

Comment: nice idea, but a tad overengineering if you ask me.

Comment: @sev - true (you're not the first one to accuse me of overengineering :P. We only have a small glimpse of the OP's requirements. Using this method would entail more development, but it would also be more robust and would support changes in the future. If the concept of "sticky" items exists in the specifications, it won't be a stretch to assume there will be more places needing this same functionality.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way would be to add a 'pinned' field to your table, and then `order by pinned, newsid`.